# Append numpy array with inequal row in a loop

Tags: python-3.x, append, numpy-ndarray

I want to append several arrays but with different size. However I don't want to merge them together, just stock them in a mega-list. Here a simplified code of mine which try to reproduce my problem:

```
import numpy as np

total_wavel = 5

tot_values = []

for i in range(total_wavel):    
    
    size = int(np.random.uniform(low=2, high=7))
    values = np.array(np.random.uniform(low=1, high=6, size=(size,)))
    
    tot_values = np.append(tot_values,values)
```

Exemple Output :

```
array([4.88776545, 4.86006097, 1.80835575, 3.52393214, 2.88971373,
       1.62978552, 4.06880898, 4.10556672, 1.33428321, 3.81505999,
       3.95533471, 2.18424975, 5.15665168, 5.38251801, 1.7403673 ,
       4.90459377, 3.44198867, 5.03055533, 3.96271897, 1.93934124,
       5.60657218, 1.24646798, 3.14179412])
```

Expected Output :

```
np.array([np.array([4.88776545, 4.86006097, 1.80835575, 3.52393214)], np.array([2.88971373,
       1.62978552, 4.06880898, 4.10556672]), np.array([1.33428321, 3.81505999,
       3.95533471, 2.18424975, 5.15665168, 5.38251801]), np.array([1.7403673 ,
       4.90459377, 3.44198867, 5.03055533], np.array([3.96271897, 1.93934124,
       5.60657218, 1.24646798, 3.14179412])])
```

Or

```
np.array([4.88776545, 4.86006097, 1.80835575, 3.52393214], [2.88971373,
       1.62978552, 4.06880898, 4.10556672],[1.33428321, 3.81505999,
       3.95533471, 2.18424975, 5.15665168, 5.38251801], [1.7403673 ,
       4.90459377, 3.44198867, 5.03055533], [3.96271897, 1.93934124,
       5.60657218, 1.24646798, 3.14179412])
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: why not just use a list? It will be more efficient.

Comment: If you want to use nested array with `np.array`, you should use this construct: `np.array([list1, list2, ...])`

Comment: Thank you guys for your answers, I'm ok with list too to be honest but @tomo_iris427 how to construct my final list like this with append? This automatically merge me all the vectors to form a 1D one. Should I use an other function to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `for` loop `tot_values.append(list(values))`, and after loop `tot_np=np.array(tot_values)`